# ReactiveMongoDatabase: How to create collection beforehand: Cannot create namespace in multi-document transaction

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, mongo-java-driver

In my `@SpringBootTest`, it seems impossible to create a collection in a ReactiveMongoDatabase, but it should be easy. Any help?

The bean is(I suppose if I want to use reactive, this is the bean I should use?)

```java
    @Bean
    Mono<MongoDatabase> reactiveMongoDatabase() {
        // recommended way in ReactiveMongoTransactionManager javadoc
        log.info("Creating reactiveMongoDatabase...");
        return ReactiveMongoDatabaseUtils.getDatabase(properties.getDatabase(), reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory());
    }
```

And in the integration test, I try to create the collection like:

```java
    @Autowired
    private ReactiveMongoTemplate template;

    @BeforeEach
    private void createColletion() {
        //mongoDatabase.createCollection("Coupon");
        template.createCollection(Coupon.class);
    }
```

But I still get the error:

```
[ENV=itest] [productName=promotion-facts-sync] [2020-03-19T14:26:09.801Z] [ERROR] [MSG=[Thread-20] e.v.c.p.f.service.SyncProcessService - Error while processing empty message. Cause: Cannot create namespace promotion-facts-sync.Coupon in multi-document transaction.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Cannot create namespace promotion-facts-sync.Coupon in multi-document transaction. ][TRACE=] [SPAN=]
```

How to do this?

Comment: May be try using `ReactiveMongoTemplate` class methods.

Comment: I tried but no effect. Check edit.

Comment: The database command in the mongod is [create](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/create/index.html#create), I'm not familiar with reactive, but you should be able to find if something uses this command or if there is a way to run a specific command.

Comment: @Joe yeah it all works in the shell, but in the code it seems no way but migration beforehand works

Answer (score 1):

Now as a workaround, I use `mongobee` for migration before any insertion. It does not support ReactiveMongoDatabase, but at least it can create the collection.

Anyone with better solution can post it, thanks.